# Websocket provider reconnects every 1 minute

Tags: web3js, events, web3-providers, websocket

I'm developing an application on a private Ethereum chain and trying to listen to some events. I wrote a basic indexer script for listening to events and writing them in a database.

To listen to the events I am connecting to the provider via `Web3.providers.WebsocketsProvider`. I realized it keeps losing the connection every minute. And actually it does not disconnect, instead, it creates a new connection every minute as I don't catch any logs from `error` or `end` events.

As a workaround, I added `reconnect` options introduced in web3.js v1.2.7. That's how I noticed the regular dropping each minute.

Here's the code:

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const TruffleContract = require('@truffle/contract');
const ReviewStorageArtifact = require('./contracts/ReviewStorage.json');
const { logAddedReview } = require('./reviewLogger'); // external module where I write to database.

const providerLink = 'wss://providerLink.org';

// Enable auto reconnection
const options = {
  reconnect: {
    auto: true,
    delay: 1000, // ms
    maxAttempts: 5,
    onTimeout: false
  }
};

// Connect
let provider, web3;
provider = new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider(providerLink, options);
web3 = new Web3(provider);

provider.on('connect', init);
provider.on('error', e => console.log('WS Error', e));
provider.on('end', e => {
  console.log(e);
  console.log('WS closed');
});

// Connect to instance and listen event
function init() {
  const ReviewStorage = TruffleContract(ReviewStorageArtifact);
  ReviewStorage.setProvider(web3.currentProvider);
  console.log('Trying to conntect weeb3');
  ReviewStorage.deployed()
    .then(instance => {
      console.log('Found instance');
      instance.ReviewAdded() // Listen to ReviewAdded events.
        .on('data', (event) => logAddedReview(event, instance))
        .on('error', console.error);
    })
    .catch(console.error);
}
```

Here's the output how I noticed the regular reconnections. Notice there are no outputs from `.on('error')` or `.on('end')`:
[image: Output of websocket reconnection]

Why could this be happening? Might it be something on the provider side? When I connect to Infura Rinkeby, for example, there are no reconnections taking place. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this options

```
const options = {
    timeout: 30000, // ms

    clientConfig: {
        // Useful if requests are large
        maxReceivedFrameSize: 100000000,   // bytes - default: 1MiB
        maxReceivedMessageSize: 100000000, // bytes - default: 8MiB

        // Useful to keep a connection alive
        keepalive: true,
        keepaliveInterval: -1 // ms
    },

    // Enable auto reconnection
    reconnect: {
        auto: true,
        delay: 1000, // ms
        maxAttempts: 10,
        onTimeout: false
    }
};
```